# Sql Query to join two table with tricky logic

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables mst_item and time_factor , mst_item has 3 columns item,location,card and time_factor has 2 columns location and card

when i am trying to join these two table using location and card columns.

The requirement is below,

mst_item

```
item     location    card
xyz       R10        CRU
ABC       R10        LAT
CCC       R14        NAC
```

time_factor

```
location     card 
R10          CRU
R10          ALL
R14          ALL
R15          FX
R15          ALL
```

The output should come as, if from mast_item table location and card both match with
location and card in time_factor table then it should return matching records,

ex-  for R10 & CRU

```
item     location    card
xyz       R10        CRU
```

if only location matches then it should return location and 'ALL' as card from time_factor table.

In any case it should not return both matching card value and 'ALL'.

ex- for R14 and NAC

```
item     location    card
CCC       R14        ALL
```

Please help me with the query logic.

Comment: What...what is the expected output given your sample table?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick...

```
select m.item, m.location, m.card from mst_card m, time_factor t
  where m.location = t.location and m.card = t.card
union all
select m.item, m.location, t.card from mst_card m, time_factor t
  where m.location = t.location and t.card = 'ALL'
    and not exists ( select 1 from time_factor t2 where t2.location=m.location and t2.card=m.card);
```

Comment: Hi Tanks for the reply, from the above query i am getting output like below,  xyz R10 CRU
 CCC R14 NAC
 ABC R10 LAT                                                  but expected output is as below  xyz R10 CRU
                                 CCC R14 ALL
                                 ABC R10 LAT          As wen i dont have any matcing card in time_factor table then ALL should retrive. Thanks agian for the reply.

Comment: your are right, there was a little bug in my query, I've fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

For returning ALL when only location matches, try following query

**SQL QUERY**

```
select m.item, m.location,
(CASE WHEN
m.card like t.card THEN m.card
ELSE
'All'
END) as card 
from 
mst_item as m,
time_factor as t 
WHERE
m.location like t.location
```

**ORACLE QUERY**

```
select mst_item.item, mst_item.location,
(CASE 
 WHEN
 mst_item.card = time_factor.card THEN mst_item.card
 ELSE
 'All'
 END) as card 
 from 
 mst_item,
 time_factor  
 WHERE
 mst_item.location like time_factor.location;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

A better query can be

**SQL QUERY**

```
select m.item, m.location,t.card
from 
mst_item as m,
time_factor as t 
WHERE
m.location like t.location
```

**ORACLE QUERY**

```
select mst_item.item, mst_item.location, time_factor.card
from 
mst_item,
time_factor  
WHERE
mst_item.location like time_factor.location;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

One other variation can be

```
select m.item, m.location,
(CASE WHEN
m.card like t.card THEN m.card
WHEN
t.card like 'ALL' THEN t.card
END) as mcard 
from 
mst_item as m,
time_factor as t 
WHERE
m.location like t.location 
AND (CASE WHEN
m.card like t.card THEN m.card
WHEN
t.card like 'ALL' THEN t.card
END) != '';
```

ONE more variant can be

**SQL QUERY**

```
select m.item, m.location,
(CASE WHEN
m.card like t.card THEN m.card
WHEN
t.card like 'ALL' THEN t.card
END) as mcard 
from 
mst_item as m,
time_factor as t 
WHERE
m.location like t.location 
AND (CASE WHEN
m.card like t.card THEN m.card
WHEN
t.card like 'ALL' THEN t.card
END) != '';
```

**ORACLE QUERY**

```
select mst_item.item, mst_item.location,
(CASE 
WHEN
mst_item.card = time_factor.card THEN mst_item.card
WHEN
time_factor.card like 'ALL' THEN time_factor.card 
END) as card 
from 
mst_item,
time_factor  
WHERE
mst_item.location like time_factor.location
AND
(CASE 
WHEN
mst_item.card = time_factor.card THEN mst_item.card
WHEN
time_factor.card like 'ALL' THEN time_factor.card 
END) IS NOT NULL
;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Please check outputs that you want so we can modify accordingly.

SQL fiddle demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53e53/21

Oracle fiddle demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d28b1/26

Comment: i think question is tagged with `Oracle`

Comment: @Deepika, thanks for the reply. Actually expected output will be like below 
item     location    card
xyz       R10        CRU
ABC       R10        ALL
CCC       R14        ALL

Once xyz for R10 CRU ,then it should negelect ALL, if nothing is there then only ALL should return.

Comment: did the queries gave you the output you wanted

Comment: xyz should negelect ALL, once it got CRU.. if no card type matches then it return default ALL. tats only issue now. Thanks again.

Comment: the solution is add GROUP BY m.item if sql

Comment: select DISTINCT A1.ITEM,A1.location,case 
          When A1.location = B1.location AND A1.card = B1.card then B1.card 
          When A1.location = B1.location AND A1.card != B1.card then 'ALL'
          End card
from A1 inner join B1 on A1.location = B1.location                        trying to run but i am not sure group by works here, as i want to exclude 'ALL' only just to keep CRU.

Comment: Third output is correct. but wen i am running below query select m.item, m.location,
(CASE WHEN
m.card like t.card THEN m.card
WHEN
t.card like 'ALL' THEN t.card
END) as mcard 
from 
mst_item as m,
time_factor as t 
WHERE
m.location like t.location 
AND (CASE WHEN
m.card like t.card THEN m.card
WHEN
t.card like 'ALL' THEN t.card
END) != ''
GROUP BY m.item;   getting not a group by expression error. My database is Oracle, running in PL/SQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you are looking for?

```
select test1.location,"card"= case 
          When test1.location = test2.location AND test1.card = test2.card then test2.card 
          When test1.location = test2.location AND test1.card != test2.card then 'ALL'
          End
from test1 inner join test2 on test1.location = test2.location
```

Here test1 is mst_item and test2 is time_factor

Here is the SQL Fiddle link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c6eb/8

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the requirement the following query will serve the purpose :

select item,mst.location,decode(mst.card,tym.card,tym.card,'ALL') 
from
    mst_item mst,
    time_factor tym
where
    mst.location=tym.location;

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
mi.item,
mi.location,
CASE
WHEN Tf_Query.location=mi.location AND Tf_Query.card=mi.card
THEN Tf_Query.card
WHEN Tf_Query.location=mi.location AND Tf_Query.card!=mi.card
THEN mi.card
END card
FROM
mst_item mi,
(SELECT
tf.location LOCATION,max(tf.card) card
FROM
time_factor tf
GROUP BY (LOCATION)) Tf_Query
WHERE
Tf_Query.LOCATION=mi.LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT item, MI.location, MI.card
FROM mst_item MI
INNER JOIN time_factor TF ON MI.location = TF.location AND MI.card = TF.card

Answer (score -1):

This can be resolved by using left outer join

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.